# How is this kernel symmetric?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-equations

[image: Eigen value and Eigen function]

I dont understand how the equation (3) has been obtained. In the first and second integral, the value of $K(t,x)$ has been put instead of $K(x,t)$. Is the kernel symmetric here ? I dont understand how the kernel is symmetric.

Comment: The first integral is an integral to $x$ with respect to $t$, and so we always have $t \le x$, in which the second clause of the definition of the kernel applies. The second integral is an integral from $x$ to $\pi$, and so we always have $x \le t$ instead.

Comment: So this means the kernel is symmetric ?

Comment: It is, but that’s not what I’m saying.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.